# How does this piece of assembly work?

Tags: assembly, x86

I recently needed to debug a program at assembly level. I don't have a lot of assembler experience, so I figured I'd write some simple C programs and single-step through them in order to get a feeling for the language before I'd start debugging other peoples code. However, I really don't get what gcc made of these two lines (compiled with -ggdb -O0):

```
items[tail] = i;
tail = (tail+1) % MAX_SIZE;
```

where MAX_SIZE is #defined to be 5 and i is a local variable (stored in 0x8(%ebp), i guess). According to gdb, this becomes:

```
0x08048394 <queue+17>:  mov    0x8049634,%edx
0x0804839a <queue+23>:  mov    0x8(%ebp),%eax
0x0804839d <queue+26>:  mov    %eax,0x804963c(,%edx,4)
0x080483a4 <queue+33>:  mov    0x8049634,%eax
0x080483a9 <queue+38>:  lea    0x1(%eax),%ecx
0x080483ac <queue+41>:  movl   $0x66666667,-0xc(%ebp)
0x080483b3 <queue+48>:  mov    -0xc(%ebp),%eax
0x080483b6 <queue+51>:  imul   %ecx
0x080483b8 <queue+53>:  sar    %edx
0x080483ba <queue+55>:  mov    %ecx,%eax
0x080483bc <queue+57>:  sar    $0x1f,%eax
0x080483bf <queue+60>:  mov    %edx,%ebx
0x080483c1 <queue+62>:  sub    %eax,%ebx
0x080483c3 <queue+64>:  mov    %ebx,-0x8(%ebp)
0x080483c6 <queue+67>:  mov    -0x8(%ebp),%eax
0x080483c9 <queue+70>:  shl    $0x2,%eax
0x080483cc <queue+73>:  add    -0x8(%ebp),%eax
0x080483cf <queue+76>:  mov    %ecx,%edx
0x080483d1 <queue+78>:  sub    %eax,%edx
0x080483d3 <queue+80>:  mov    %edx,-0x8(%ebp)
0x080483d6 <queue+83>:  mov    -0x8(%ebp),%ebx
0x080483d9 <queue+86>:  mov    %ebx,0x804963
```

Since 0x804963c is the address of items, i can see how the first line of C code works. Also, 0x8049634 is the address of tail, so I guess queue+33 and queue+38 are equivalent to %ecx = tail+1...but I have no idea what is happening afterwards. Who would have thought a simple modulo could be this complicated?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's a way to avoid having to do a more expensive division instruction. I was also quite stumped the first time I encountered this. The fun thing is that searching for the magic numbers that are used for this trick (in this case `0x66666667`) often gives results explaining this trick. (I believe at the time it was the only concrete thing I had to go on because I didn't have the sources.)

A quick search gave me this blog post: http://blog.dkbza.org/2007/09/reverse-engineering-compiler-produced.html It has some useful links at the bottom (including an indirect link to a paper on this trick).